# How to split Regular Expression in Nintex

Tags: split, sharepoint-2010, nintex-workflow

I am trying to split a value in Nintex, Sharepoint 2010
My value: `ABCD\123456`
I want to split `"\"` and return this:
`ABCD`
`123456`

But when I try this, it returns an error:
`Error in regular expression action. parsing "\" - Illegal \ at end of pattern.`

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with sharepoint, but try escaping that slash - instead of just \, do \\.

Comment: i tryed... it didnt work

Comment: It'd probably help to list the things you've tried and what they did, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Mike gave the correct answer

Just use "\\" instead of "\" in the Pattern.
I tried this by creating a sample workflow and it is working fine with "\\".

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the backslash is the correct answer.

In general, Nintex uses .NET regular expressions (REs). Look for an online .NET RE tester (there are a few). It will help you a lot when you're debugging REs.